# C# Multithreading API calls

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am multithreading a list of API calls in Python like so:

```
from requests_toolbelt.threaded import pool
import multiprocessing
import api_credentials
import queue

def multi_process(urls)

    cores_to_use = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    if cores_to_use > 10: cores_to_use = 10

    jobs = queue.Queue()
    for url in urls():
        jobs.put({'method': 'GET', 'url': url, 'auth':(api_credentials.username, api_credentials.password)
    
    pool_of_jobs = pool.Pool(job_queue=jobs, num_processes=cores_to_use)
    pool_of_jobs.join_all()

    return pool_of_jobs.responses()
```

What is the equivalent way of doing the above in C#?

I am getting the number of cores from:

`int cores_to_use = Environment.ProcessorCount;`

but I haven't found any clear example to achieve the above in C#.

Comment: Have a look into [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).

Comment: This is multithreading.

Comment: title, description and tagging edited

Comment: What are the API calls, synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: the above method does it asynchronously

Comment: Parallell.ForEach might help you out here. You can specify the MaxDegreeOfParallelism which will set the upper bound for the maximum number of threads which can be used. However Parallell.ForEach might use fewer threads than specified for performance issues.